# Javascript Regex for string containing more b's than a's

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression in Javascript such that the string contains more b's than a's. Can contain other characters anywhere but b's have to be more than a's. Could anybody help?

Comment: does it have to be with regex? counting a's then counting b's and finally comparing seems a good straightforward solution

Comment: Yes unfortunately. I have to do it with a regex to construct strings in that format

Comment: @AdityaSawant You will not be able to tell regex that you want more of one character than another. You can use quantifiers, but those work on a per-character basis.

Comment: I believe that might be the case. I have been asked this question and haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest route:

```js
let moreAsThanBs = (str) => str.match(/a/ig).length > str.match(/b/ig).length;

console.log(moreAsThanBs("Are there more As than Bs in this sentence?"));
console.log(moreAsThanBs("Are there more As than BBBBBs in this sentence?"));
```

Comment: While its good, unfortunately that is not the solution required. I need to build a regex which have more b's than a's. Strings such as 'bab', 'baaabbb', 'basdfsdfsdb'  and 'b' can match but 'aab' , 'baa', 'aaa', 'asdfb' cannot match.